# Issue with name space handler

Tags: spring, maven

Please help us to resolve the below issue.

The following is the issue we are facing, when we are building the interface via Maven command(`mvn clean package`).
Can you please try to help on this issue?

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration problem:
>   Failed to import bean definitions from URL location
>   [classpath:common-config.xml]
>           Offending resource: URL [file:C:/AnypointStudio/projectname/src/test/munit/new-test-suite.xml];
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace
>   [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security]
>           Offending resource: class path resource [common-config.xml] (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
>                           at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:59)
>                           at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:45)
>                           at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.runTestSuite(RemoteRunner.java:75)
>                           at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.run(RemoteRunner.java:55)
>                           at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.main(RemoteRunner.java:39)
>           Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL
>   location 
>           Offending resource: URL [file:/C: Projectname/new-test-suite.xml]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace

[http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by adding jersey dependency in pom.xml

Thanks for your time , who look into issue